# consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 61 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I'm trying to get celery up and running on Heroku as per the woeful instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku)

whenever i try to run "heroku local"

it gives me the error:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 61 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379.         
Connection refused..
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To run celery locally, you need to install to [install and start the redis server](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart). If you're using Docker, you might find it easiest to use [the Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis). If you aren't comfortable compiling redis or using Docker, then search for a guide for your OS, or if you say which OS you're using somebody here might have a suggestion.

Comment: i am using OSX.

Answer (score 1):

you have to run the server

```
$ redis-server
```

this work for me